# setTimeout function associated with a event

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to be able to call my function of setTimeout when a user enter a number in my input after 1s.

But the problem i want that this event is called just once for example when a user enter **3** numbers like **200** in a time less than 1s.

My code below is called 3 time if a user enter 3 numbers like 200

```
    $('input.amount').on('input.amount',function(e){

        setTimeout(function() {
            // code
        }, 1000);
    });
```

So i want that this code is called just once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach I would take is to delay the execution till after 1000ms after the last input

```
var timer;
$('input.amount').on('input.amount', function (e) {
    if (timer) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        // code
        timer = undefined;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: @Youssef what it does is if a second input event is fired before first timeout is done then the first timeout is cancelled and then we create a new timeout...

Comment: thanks and i think your solution is more appropriate for my case.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to keep a variable that tells you if the user already typed a character. Then only trigger the function if the variable is not yet set. For example:

```
   var started = false;
   $('input.amount').on('input',function(e){
        if(!started){
            started = true;
            setTimeout(function() {
                // code
                started = false;//to reset so that further typing will trigger again
            }, 1000);
        }
   });
```

Comment: your solution is the answer for my question but when i see @ArunPJohny 's solution it's more appropriate because the event will be not fired till the last input even if the user make 5 sec to enter a value in the input